# How to send Delete Response on Delete Mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVGMs.png)

How I fix it and perform both the operation . If I perform separately , first delete and then return noContent() then it's work but Is there any trick to Check If the operation is performed or not If not then return NOTFOUND.

Comment: You should return some data from your service method (for example boolean), that indicates if entity was deleted or not, and depending on it's result return NO_CONTENT or NOT_FOUND from controller.

Comment: I never return anything other than a 204 (no content) for delete operations (unless there's an error during deletion).  This is because the client asks you to delete the entity; delete it and respond with a 204.  If it doesn't exist, it is already deleted; respond with a 204.  Don't return a 404 that will require your consumer to handle. They asked for the entity to be deleted, and it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the deletion operation is successful or not and return NOT_FOUND if it fails, you can modify your code by checking the result of the deletion operation before returning the response.

```
@DeleteMapping("/{hotelId}")
public ResponseEntity<?> deleteHotel(@PathVariable String hotelId) {
    boolean deletionSuccessful = hotelService.delete(hotelId);

    if (deletionSuccessful) {
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
}
```